# How to get the tab title and index in Jeasy-ui

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

we have to 4 tabs from which we have to find the titles of each tab and set some property to each tab based on its title.

How can i get such title over iterating set of tabs. I have reached Iterating the tab? What to do next?

Thanks in Advance.

```
var tabs = $('#tt').tabs('tabs');
for(i=0; i<tabs.length; i++)
{
 /*
 How can i code here to get the each tab title. if tab title is "First Tab" i have to set some to that tab.
 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#tt ul.tabs li').each(function(i, v) {
    var elTitle = $('.tabs-title', v);
    var title = elTitle.html();
    alert('found titile ' + title + ' at ' + i);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kVS7S/)

Comment: Thanks it is working. do u have idea how can i get tab name from the first posted method

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var tabs = $('#tt ul.tabs li').size();
for (var i = 0; i < tabs; i++) { 
   var title = $('#tt .tabs-title')[i].innerHTML;
   alert('Found titile ' + title + ' at ' + i);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D5Gm8/